# Converting JavaScript numbers into Dart doubles

Tags: javascript, dart

I am calling a JavaScript library from Dart using Dart Interop.

This library sometimes returns `number` objects - how can I convert them into Dart `double`s?

The Javascript `number` object has [a few methods](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_number.asp) that might be useful, but I am not sure how to invoke them.

Here is my Dart code - the comments are the types identified by the Dart debugger:

```
myObject = collection[i]; //Proxy
a = myObject.value; //FunctionProxy
```

The `value` is of type `number`, according to the docs for the JavaScript, but I don't see how to convert the `a` into a double. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `a` variable is a `FunctionProxy`, the `value` member of `myObject` should be a function. So you should have used :

```dart
a = myObject.value();
```

Now `a` should be a [Dart num](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_core/num.html) which contains almost all [javascript Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) functions and more.